# How do I configure systemjs to recognize an environment-specific app path?

Tags: angular, tomcat, angular-cli, systemjs

I wrote a web app using Angular and angular-cli. It's up and running when using `ng serve`.

However, I need to deploy it on Tomcat where it must be accessible under a different path because my Web App cannot be the default servlet.

On my development server using `ng serve` I can access the Web App here:

```
http://<<ng serve>>:4200/index.html
```

On my Tomcat production server it needs to be here:

```
http://<<prod-server>>:8080/MyWebAppName/index.html
```

The problem is that system.js still searches for its dependency in `http://<<prod-server>>:8080/vendor/...` instead of 
`http://<<prod-server>>:8080/MyWebAppName/vendor/...`

How can I tell system.js to load its dependencies from another path but only for my production system?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the name of your webapp to `ROOT` and deploy it again on tomcat, then your application can be accessed on `http://<<prod-server>>:8080/index.html`

Comment: Thank you, but sorry. I may not do this, as this is not "my" Tomcat. That's what I meant with "my App cannot be the default servlet"

Answer (score 0):

In your index.html you need to add `<base href="./" />`
If you are using webpack, see [Deploying Spring Boot WAR to Tomcat 8 - HTTP 404 when accessing resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187237/deploying-spring-boot-war-to-tomcat-8-http-404-when-accessing-resources/40907131#40907131)